# Push rejected, failed to compile ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

currently i am at chapter 3 of michael hartl's tutorial and i keep running into this problem:

```
C:/Users/HuiHui/sutdweb/spec/spec_helper.rb:82:in `block in <top (required)>': u
ninitialized constant Capybara (NameError)
```

This is my Gemfile.rb:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '4.1.1'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.1', :require => 'sqlite3'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.3.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

and this is my spec_helper.rb:

```
    # This file was generated by the `rails generate rspec:install` command. Conventionally, all
# specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
# The generated `.rspec` file contains `--require spec_helper` which will cause this
# file to always be loaded, without a need to explicitly require it in any files.
#
# Given that it is always loaded, you are encouraged to keep this file as
# light-weight as possible. Requiring heavyweight dependencies from this file
# will add to the boot time of your test suite on EVERY test run, even for an
# individual file that may not need all of that loaded. Instead, make a
# separate helper file that requires this one and then use it only in the specs
# that actually need it.
#
# The `.rspec` file also contains a few flags that are not defaults but that
# users commonly want.
#
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
# require 'rspec/rails'
# require 'active_support'
# require 'active_support/core_ext'
require 'rspec/Rails'
require 'capybara/Rails'
RSpec.configure do |config|

# The settings below are suggested to provide a good initial experience
# with RSpec, but feel free to customize to your heart's content.

  # These two settings work together to allow you to limit a spec run
  # to individual examples or groups you care about by tagging them with
  # `:focus` metadata. When nothing is tagged with `:focus`, all examples
  # get run.
  config.filter_run :focus
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
  # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
  # individual spec file.
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
    # unless a formatter has already been configured
    # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end

  # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
  # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
  # particularly slow.
  config.profile_examples = 10

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = :random

  # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
  # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
  # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
  # as the one that triggered the failure.
  Kernel.srand config.seed

  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # Enable only the newer, non-monkey-patching expect syntax.
    # For more details, see:
    #   - http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax
    expectations.syntax = :expect
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Enable only the newer, non-monkey-patching expect syntax.
    # For more details, see:
    #   - http://teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
    mocks.syntax = :expect

    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

rails_helper.rb:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
# run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
# in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
# run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
# end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with with the --pattern
# option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

when i did `git push heroku`, they gave me the following error:

```
       Installing rdoc 3.12.2
       Installing pg 0.15.1
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3-ruby (1.3.1), and Bundler cann
ot
       continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3-ruby -v '1.3.1'` succeeds before bund
ling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:sutdweb.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:sutdweb.git'
```

why is the push rejected? can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Heroku is trying to install SQLite, which of course it doesn't support, as pointed out by this error message: "*etected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.*" I see in your Gemfile that you don't have it set for production though. Did you forget to commit your Gemfile changes to Git?

Comment: One more thing, Ruby on Rails development is easier on OS X than on Windows, OS X has more tools available to support it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in testing ruby on rails using rspec in tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246926/error-in-testing-ruby-on-rails-using-rspec-in-tutorial)

Comment: please tell me why you need two `_helper.rb` files?

Comment: @Cupcake yeah i know os x would most probably make my life much easier... but currently i do not have access to os x and my virtual machines do not run as well...

Comment: @PhilidorGreen it was already in so i just posted it to provide more info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Capybara**

In your `Gemfile`, move `capybara` out of your `test` gems :

```
#Gemfile
gem `capybara`
```

Heroku will only install the `generic` and `production` gems (I.E use the `bundle install --without test development` command)

This will mean that when you use the `require 'Capybara'` command without having the gem installed in Heroku, you'll end up with the error you've received.

-

**Sqlite**

Secondly, you're trying to install the SQLite gem, which is not supported by Heroku.

Get rid of the SQLite gem from your `production` gem file like this:

```
#Gemfile
group :development do
    gem 'sqlite'
end
```

This should help your system install the remaining gems to get it working

As mentioned by `@cupcake`, it seems your Gemfile does have `SQLite` in the `development` group - however you are referencing another gem 
`gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.1', :require => 'sqlite3'` -> this should be placed into your `development` group too:

```
#Gemfile
group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.1', :require => 'sqlite3'
end
```

---

If you apply the changes to your Gemfile, you should then perform the following steps:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "Heroku"
$ git push heroku master
```

Comment: He doesn't have the SQLite gem set up in production, look at the Gemfile. I suspect that the user forgot to commit it to Git.

Comment: `gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.1', :require => 'sqlite3'` ?

Comment: Oh...yeah, that would do it. I was looking at the development block.